# Cascading calls for state update

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

Few questions regarding this approach: https://medium.com/@thomasburlesonIA/push-based-architectures-with-rxjs-81b327d7c32d

1. Is there any general, well known name for such architecture, which I can search for? (Not easy to find)
2. I faced problem where I have a state i.e

```
    interface AppState = {
     account: Account,
     servers: Server[]
    }

    interface Server {
     name: string;
     details: ServerDetails;
    }

    let state: AppState = {
      account: null,
      servers: null
    }
```

My intention is to load details on demand when user change router i.e localhost/server/srvname
So in other words, details are fetched in ngOnInit of details component.

But when user enter url directly (localhost/server/srvname) it will skip let say previous components that usually will load Server and even AppState data. I have null in AppState.servers and cannot update state.

How to handle such loading in nice way. Should I handle it manually i.e

```
getDetails(server: string) {
 this.loadServer(server); // load server before details
 this.loadDetauls(server);
 this.updateAppState();
}
```

Or put properites into model doing kind of onDemand from ORM?

Or there is good pattern or well know approach for this? Or ngrx handle such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the router structure to make parent/child components, and separate by that way responsibilities on what every component should be responsible for.

for example your app component will be always load first so it can be responsible to load the initial configurations by execuiting the services on its OnInit cycle, after this it will load the component defined for the route you are tying to load.

if you prefer to separate in modules you can create a server module with a structured wouter to load the initial services in a component and then create the child component to load the details

for the module approach the router will be something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {
        path: '',
        component: ServerComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'details',
            loadChildren: () => import('./components/server-details/server-details.module').then(m => m.ServerDetailsModule)
          },
        ]
      },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
   export class ServerRoutingModule { }
```